# Пустой результат поиска по сайту

Tags: php, sql

Это код:

```
    if($_GET['find']){
        $text=$_GET['text'];
        $text=preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$text);

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE username LIKE '%$text%' OR surname LIKE '%$text%' OR name LIKE '%$text%' OR lastName LIKE '%$text%'") or die("netu");
        $count=mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($count==0){
            echo "<h2 style='font-size:22px;'>Ничего не найдено!</h2>";
        }else if($count!=0){
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $login=$row['username'];
                $surname=$row['surname'];
                $name=$row['name'];
                $lastName=$row['lastName'];

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td class='num'>1</td>";
                echo "<td class='log'><a href='../profile.php?=".$_GET['id']."'>".$login."</a></td>";
                echo "<td class='fio'><p>".$surname." ".$name." ".$lastName."</p></td>";
                if($admin){
                    echo "<td class='action'><a href='../deleteProfile.php'>Удалить</a></td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }

        }else{mysql_error();}
    }
```

И этот код ищет один раз, то-есть, в первый раз он находить но если попытаться найти еще раз что-угодно, он возвращает сайт без данных, но дизайн остается

Comment: Можно предположить, что этот кусок не причем. А что то происходит например с `<form>` на странице, ссылка не туда ведет или какие то данные кривые или название инпута меняется или еще что не так. потому как не может БД один раз искать а другой нет, что то не так с входными параметрами от клиента